# Why was my flag declined?

Tags: support, flagging

> [image: declined]

Why was this declined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flags for the matter you discuss are not the appropriate place for appealing sanctions applied to your account. 
We have no relation or responsibility to matters regarding Meta or Music. Furthermore we cannot (and will not) speak for Meta.SE or Music.SE. Moderators are not shared between such sites and have no direct context of your situation.

If you have issues about your account or suspension please contact the community team via email at `team@stackoverflow.com` or use the [contact form](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact).